# python でtxtファイルを開きたい。

Tags: python, python3

python3でtxtファイルを開きたいのですが、エラーが発生してファイルが開けないと表示されるので質問させて頂きます。

ルートディレクトリにある`tmp`フォルダに保存した`data.txt`を`python`から開きたいのですが以下のコードを実行するとそんなファイルは存在しないとエラーが出ます。

```
wordlist_file = '/tmp/data.txt'

fp = open(wordlist_file, 'rb')
    raw_words = fp.readlines()
    fp.close()
```

エラー

```
builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/data.txt'
```

コードを実行している場所が`/root/pythonstudy/`になっていてrootディレクトリとtmpディレクトリは同じ階層にあってパスが上手く通ってないと思うのですが、どのようにパスを書いたら良いのかわかりません。
それでも相対パスでなく、絶対パスなので上手く行くと考えていたのですがどうしてでしょうか？pythonの仕様だったりするのでしょうか？
詳しい方、回答して頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル拡張子の.txtが抜けていました。追加したら表示できました。

<sub>-- [質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/22565/wataru)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41607/python-%E3%81%A7txt%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#comment42713_41608)より</sub>

Answer (score 0):

OSはwindowsですか？
単純にtmpフォルダかdata.txtファイルが存在しないだけとか。

Comment: OSはdebianを使用しています。tmpとdata.txtは確認しましたがあります。

Comment: ファイル拡張子の.txtが抜けていました。追加したら表示できました。